# K2 tag not working on joomla 2.5 backend

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

Hi after searching a lot I,m posting this question. When trying to add a tag in k2 item in joomla 2.5 backend, nothing happens. I have pressed enter and also tried with comma. I have tried with updating k2 latest version. But still same problem. I,m using ja_wall template, joomla 2.5. Also I,m getting this error after k2 upgrade

```
Model class cpanelModelCpanel not found in file
```

Can anyone help please.

Comment: This sounds like an issue for Joomla's or K2's support resources rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: no I didn't find any error in firebug. @Pekka I wrote I searched everywhere . Then come to steak overflow

Comment: So you read, for example, http://getk2.org/community/New-to-K2-Ask-here-first/163115-Model-class-cpanelModelCpanel-not-found and it didn't help you?

Comment: yes I posted a question there too. Can you help ?

Comment: Did you install the latest release as is recommended in the link I posted?

Comment: yes I have installed latest release

Answer (score 0):

This was a issue that was fixed in K2 v2.6.1. Alternatively delete the file `ROOT/administrator/components/com_k2/models/cpanel.php`. Which was effectively what the update did.

Also see [this](http://getk2.org/community/New-to-K2-Ask-here-first/163115-Model-class-cpanelModelCpanel-not-found) forum post on k2 for more info on the issue!!

Comment: Hello Willson. ModelCpanel is not the main issue. Its solved by updating k2. But my problem is tag not working in backend. I can,t save any tag. Please help

Comment: Have you tried adding a tag in the 'tag' area section of the backend? Does that save?

Comment: no I can't save that. Thats the problem, After hiting comma or enter process starts and suddenly stops :(

Comment: But there is a tag tab in the backend where you can manage the tags created or add new ones. I'm not talking about the article editor for now

Comment: Also have you checked the table exists in PHP myadmin or where ever? and if there is anything in your error log?

Comment: THANKS A LOT MAN, I didn't noticed that functionality. You saved me. It works if I add a new tag in tag tab and then type it in item editor. But why it don't work directly in article editor ?

Comment: I don't know! It shouldn't make a difference. Have you made any modifications? Glad it's fixed though!

Answer (score 0):

I have the right solution. Go to phpMyadmin then to jos_k2_tags_xref and edit the structure. Set the ID as a Primary, (click on it) then go to edit the id row. Set "Default" as "None" or "Not Set" (I don't know how it is called in english but anyway it's the first possible selection) then check the "A_I" field (AUTO_INCREMENT) and then save. Now it should work :)

The problem was, ID of new k2 tags was 0 due to a wrong migration of k2 tables :)

This can also used to fix the same error when creating/copying/deleting k2 items if this cause problems.